# Does anyone know the equation for the graph these points fall onto?

Tags: graphing-functions

I need to write an equation to determine how rotating a digital balls path with the ball as the center of rotation effects the amount it moves on the x&y axis each frame. I made a table of points on the equation to help me write it, but I'm unable to convert the equation into points. I linked an image of the table here. Does anyone know the answer? I think it's a helix. It's fine if you need to switch which axis each column corresponds to in the equation, as long as you mention which ones you switched.

[Click here to see the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duQRx.png)

Comment: Your points are just $(\sin x, \cos x)$ for angle $x$.

Comment: Adding on to @Ethan Bolker , you could do something like $y= cos(sin^{-1}(x))$